# sed inser a work insid parenthesis

Tags: sed

I want to insert a word (public) inside parenthesis with sed keep getting error "unterminated s"  what is the error on my command ? thanks

`sed -e 's/\:read \(\)/\:read\(public\)/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, you shouldn't escape parenthesis.

`sed -e 's/\:read ()/\:read\(public\)/'`

for in place edit use the `-i` option.

`sed -i -e 's/\:read ()/\:read\(public\)/' filename`

Comment: actually the bonus answer perfectly full fill my objective.